# Vimba C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently trying to include the vimba c++ api in my existing project to communicate with a camera.
Including the namespace works:

```
using namespace AVT::VmbAPI;
```

But when I call any function of the api,
`VimbaSystem &system = VimbaSystem::GetInstance();` 
the programm finishes unexpectedly without throughing any error.

As my project is written with Qt, I dont want to change to VS.
Anyone already used vimba with Qt?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my braindead body forgot to put the .dll into the build-folder and of course this error isnt shown in the Qt Console. You can get it by executing the .exe direclty.
Just copy the .dll into your build-folder.